# How do i change like texture into animation

Tags: texturing

I am creating face texture. trying make him talking with textures animation but i dont know how to do it.
[image]

Comment: Hey there and welcome. Found this tutorial: [How To Make 2D Eyes in Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJDLkfiUv94), maybe it can help you get an idea. Search for UV animation and you may find some more.

Comment: well i try the view you link but there is a problem it wont export into unity.

Comment: The question did **not include** any hint towards **unity**. But since there are no answers yet, it might be an idea to just use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/175126/edit) function to adjust it and add unity as a target in your question. Questions should though be limited to 1 topic/problem to allow for a clear and focused answer. Thus i'd like to recommend to adjust the question to clearly state what your target/problem is. It's also a good idea to check out [how to ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).